# Does it make sense to create a `Copyable` type interface instead of using `Cloneable`?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a bit of code that requires a copy of an object be sent in. This requirement is because a service (runtime library) that is called modifies the object sent. This object also needs to expose setters, in case the `doThing` method below needs to set any field in the `ImportantObj` class. This implementation is pending change, but does not have a reasonable expectation to be changed in the near future. My workaround is to provide a class that does as follows:

```
public class DangerousCallWrapper<T> implements DangerousCaller<T> {
  public T doThing(T dataObject) {

      T cloneOfDataObject = #Clone of dataObject

      // This service modifies the cloneOfDataObject... dangerous! 
      Optional<T> result = service.doThing(cloneOfDataObject);

      return result.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No data object returned");
  }
}

public interface DangerousCaller<T> {

  /**
  * Performs the functionality of the DangerousService
  */
  public T doThing(T);
}


public DangerousService<T> {


  public T doThing(T data) {
   data.importantField = null;
   data.thing = "Done!";

   return data;
  }
}

public static void main() {

  DangerousService service = new DangerousService<ImportantObj>();
  ImportantObj important = new ImportantObj().setImportantField("Password for my bank account").setThing("Undone");
  service.doThing(important);
  //would fail this check
  assertNotNull(important.importantField);

  DangerousCallWrapper wrapper = new DangerousCallWrapper<ImportantObj>();
  ImportantObj important = new ImportantObj().setImportantField("Password for my bank account").setThing("Undone");
  service.doThing(important);
  //would not fail this check
  assertNotNull(important.importantField);
}
```

So the first line of that method is where I am stuck. It is a generic type, so I can't explicitly call some cloning utility like Jackson, or similar.

So I thought I would just add `T extends Cloneable` to the method... but I opened the can of worms that `Cloneable` is beyond taboo (https://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html). I have also read that copy constructors are probably the best way to handle this... However, I am unsure of how to denote that using the generics.

So my thought was to provide an interface `Copyable` that does what you would expect `Cloneable` to do: expose a method, `copy()` that will create a new instance of the class.

Does this constitute a viable approach?

Comment: `Cloneable` is OK as long as you're careful, and you can ensure that everyone after you is just as careful too.  `Copyable` could work and might not have some problems that `Cloneable` does, but it's a non-standard interface and folks will have to be just as careful.  The other thing to do is use `Serializable`, just serialize to a memory buffer and deserialize the object back.  Note this can create problems too though.

Comment: The *best* way to do this is to make your objects immutable if at all possible and to use withers or similar to perform mutations.

Comment: Unfortunately, immutable objects/controlling mutability is not a possibility. Due to the implementation of `DangerousService`, mutation is required on the object passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to polymorphically make a copy of `dataObject` like this:

```
T cloneOfDataObject = dataObject.clone();
```

and the issue is that `Cloneable` does not have a `clone()` method, so the above does not compile.

Given this premise, it does make sense to create your own `Copyable` interface that defines a `clone()` method so you can leverage already-implemented `clone()` methods (if they exist) on the classes of your data object. For maximum effectiveness this interface would need to be generic as well:

```
interface Copyable<T> {
    public T clone();
}
```

and the type bound:

```
public class DangerousCallWrapper<T extends Copyable<T>> 
    implements DangerousCaller<T> {
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of having `Copyable`  expose `clone()` instead of `copy()`?